# Selecting Multiple XPATHs With Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new here and to Selenium in general.

I'm building a project to automatically order products.

What I need at the moment is to fill multiple fields with data from excel, and I don't know how to copy the XPATHs from each field automatically.

In the picture one of the fields is highlighted in blue, I need the XPATH of it, and the XPath of the above, and so on (or other solution)

Anyone can help me with this?

[Fields to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7NKQ.png)

My code at the moment is:

```
#IMPORTAÇÕES PARA LER EXCEL
    import pandas as pd

#IMPORTAÇÕES PARA AUTOMATIZAR WEB
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    nome_do_arquivo = 'teste.xlsx'

    df = pd.read_excel(nome_do_arquivo)

    chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
    chrome.get("https://extranet.grupoboticario.com.br/mfe/mar/semanal")
```

Comment: right-click on each field and choose, "Inpect".  That'll give you the DOM-view of that element.  Try to find an "id" or "name" attribute, and then write your XPATH to target that attribute.

Comment: Adding to @pcalkins, you can also use third party browser extensions that generate xpath when you right click